# How to use CASE condition when using more than one table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I want to use case statement to check expiry of credit card. I have two tables -

1. Table_A - account_no, account_id
2. Table_B - account_no, account_status, date_of_card_expiry

Data types of above fields are -
account_no - NUMBER, account_id - NUMBER, account_status - NUMBER, date_of_card_expiry - CHAR

I have to write query to check if card will expire in 30 days or 60 days. Below is the query I have but its giving invalid relational operator error at line 4.

```
SELECT a.account_no, a.account_id, b.account_status,b.date_of_card_expiry
  FROM Table_A a
  JOIN Table_B b
    ON (a.account_no = b.account_no
   AND a.account_id IN ('1','2','7')
   AND (
         CASE WHEN (to_date(b.date_of_card_expiry, 'MMYY')) = to_date(to_char(sysdate+60, 'MMYY'),'MMYY') then 'card will expire after 2 months'
         CASE WHEN (to_date(b.date_of_card_expiry, 'MMYY')) = to_date(to_char(sysdate+30, 'MMYY'),'MMYY') then 'card will expire after 1 month'))
```

Please help me to correct the query.

Comment: what is the message from the db ?

Comment: It shows invalid relational operator at line 4

Comment: Normally you have to join two table on column that are in common. After the first ON clause you should have a WHERE (not AND). After that, maybe you are selecting a wrong name in the join.

Comment: See ? In Table_B, you don't have account_id

Comment: @SébastienBémelmans - What you say about what should be in the ON clause of a join is completely wrong. Conditions on columns from a single table may be either in the ON clause or in the WHERE clause - and it **does** make a difference when the join is an outer join. (Often the conditions, either from the ON clause or the WHERE clause of a join, will be "pushed" earlier to each individual table whenever possible and whenever the optimizer thinks it's more efficient.)

Comment: @Puja - A few questions for you. First: if `account_id` is number, why are you comparing it to strings like `'1', '2', '7'` in the `IN` condition? You should compare to numbers `1, 2, 7`. Second: If a card expires **0820**, doesn't that mean August **31**, 2020? If you convert the string `'0820` to a date using `to_date` with the format model `'mmyy'`, Oracle uses a default for the day-of-the-month, and that default is the **first** day, not the **last** day. You will need help to write code that is correct from the point of view of your business, not just "without syntax errors".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use the criteria as a column, as follows.

I have modified the criteria logic, to be as follows, if the diff of days between today and card_expiry_date is more than 60 days, then its marked up as 'card expires after 2 months' and more than 30 days, to read 'card expires after 1 month'. But i think you would also needs an else part to show up if the diff in dates dont meet either of the two criteria

```
SELECT a.account_no, a.account_id, b.account_status,b.date_of_card_expiry
       ,CASE WHEN  to_date(b.date_of_card_expiry, 'MMYY')-trunc(sysdate)>=60 then 
                  'card will expire after 2 months'
             WHEN to_date(b.date_of_card_expiry, 'MMYY')-trunc(sysdate)>=30  then 
                  'card will expire after 1 month'
        END as card_status
  FROM Table_A a
  JOIN Table_B b
    ON (a.account_no = b.account_no
   AND a.account_id IN ('1','2','7')
```

Comment: Thanks @George , this solves my problem.. just added else part as well